# php printing array element with space

Tags: php

here is my code, I want to print single space between each array element
problem i am facing is m getting space on every element but there is space for 1st element also

```
$handle = fopen ("php://stdin","r");
fscanf($handle,"%d",$n);
$arr_temp = fgets($handle);
$arr = explode(" ",$arr_temp);
array_walk($arr,'intval');
for($i=sizeof($arr);$i>=0;$i--)
{

  echo $arr[$i]." ";

} 

 ?>
```

my output is " 2 3 4 1" i want "2 3 4 1"
there is space in the 1st element.

Comment: Add `isset($arr[$i])&&$arr[$i]!=""?$arr[$i]." ":""` to ignore not set and blank value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ltrim will remove spaces from left side

```
echo ltrim($arr[$i])." ";
```

Answer (score 1):

use `ltrim()` it will remove space from left end

read [documentation](http://php.net/manual/en/function.ltrim.php) for further details

Comment: @pranavmandlik please mark the answer as accepted so other developers know it has been answered.

Comment: yes sure but its saying you can accept answer in 10 minutes